# Upgrading CentOS Downtime?

Tags: centos5

I'd like to update CentOS from 5.8 to 5.9 since I've been advised that there are security issues in my current version. Since it's not a major release, should I expect any downtime?

Also, are the automatic backups done by WHM/cPanel sufficient for this in case anything goes wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only downtime for this update will be the time it takes you to reboot. You'll have a new kernel for 5.9, but all other OS packages can be updated via `yum update` with no downtime.